# Javascript's Boolean translation to Golang

Tags: go

In JavaScript I see functions like:

```
function SomeFunc(i) {
    var f = 0x80000000;

    return Boolean(i & f);
}
```

What would be an analog in Golang? First of all, I see **0x80000000** is not possible, syntax is the second question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, coercing any non-boolean value to boolean just does a "falsiness" check; for the most part, any non-empty value is false and everything else is true. So the Go equivalent for an integer value would simply be:

```
return i != 0
```

Comment: **0x80000000** seems to be important, but I can't do `(i & 0x80000000) != 0`

Answer (score 1):

To put it all together

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
//function SomeFunc(i) {
//    var f = 0x80000000;
//
 //   return Boolean(i & f);
//}

func SomeFunc(i uint64) bool{
 return i & 0x80000000 != 0
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(SomeFunc(0x800))
    fmt.Println(SomeFunc(0x81234567))
}
```